# Matlab fails to read JAR resources

Tags: java, matlab, resources, jar

I am using Matlab with Java integration and am able to link Java JAR files, enabling me to both create Java objects and call methods from within Matlab. The problem is with resources. For example, if I have an XML file located in the root of the JAR I can load it successfully from within a Java app, but not from Matlab.

Does anyone have an idea on how to make Matlab access resources within JAR files?

Thanks.

Comment: Do these libraries rely on JNI libraries by any chance? Then you will have to make sure the native libraries that come with MATLAB are compatible with the formers.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a jar file to MATLAB's dynamic java classpath (e.g. using javaaddpath) the resources contained in the jar will NOT be visible to any java code.  As discussed in [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/259499) post, items on MATLAB's dynamic classpath are not really on the classpath of the JVM.  In order to access the resources in my jar file I resorted to adding the jar to the static classpath.  This can be accomplished in MATLAB R2012b by creating a file named javaclasspath.txt in the directory you start MATLAB that contains a list of the jar files you are using.  [Relevant MATLAB documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/bringing-java-classes-and-methods-into-matlab-workspace.html)

Answer (score 0):

The normal Java `Class.getResource` methods should work when called from Matlab. What syntax are you using to try to load the resource in Java and in Matlab? If using `getResource`, are you calling it on a Class that was loaded from the same JAR that holds the resource?

In Matlab, classes on the static and dynamic classpaths use different ClassLoaders. Resources in a JAR on the dynamic classpath may not be visible to classes on the static classpath. So if your JAR is on the dynamic classpath, you need to make sure `getResource` is invoked on a class that came from that same ClassLoader.

Comment: Class.getResource() returns a valid java.net.URL describing the resource, but then calling URL.openStream (within MATLAB) throws a FileNotFoundException

Comment: That's a bit surprising; I would expect that getResource() would return null in the case of the simple static/dynamic classpath mismatch I was talking about, but that if you got a URL object back then the openStream() would work. Could you add a concrete example, with the URL string you got, the exact error message of that FileNotFoundException, and if possible the exact Matlab code making those calls? Could you also try breaking the openStream() call in to separate openConnection() and getInputStream() calls to see exactly where the error is happening?

Comment: Oh, sorry Clark, I thought you were OP leaving a comment. Do you have a repro of the same situation?